# How to convey the point (on a resume) that you solved a problem that lasted for years?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, programming

I want to say that I solved a programming bug and has been around for years in my resume. I currently have something like "Debugged long standing  bug" but I don't think it conveys that point that this issue has persisted for many years.

I could obviously say "Debugged bug that has been around for many years" but that doesn't sound like resume-language

Answer (score 2):

I understand Resume language likes to be short and begin with the verb. I would suggest, *"Credited with solving long standing software bug answering years of difficulty"* Or *"Solved long standing software bug solving years of difficulty"* You could use *resolving years of* but I would hate to see both in the same sentence.

The unstated and primary part of the job description is always "Solving bugs". The least impressive resume sentence would be *"Solved a bug for the employer."* (Really! How proud you must be.) In your case, as you know, it is the fact that it has been around for years that makes it worth reporting. The bug must be described as *long standing* (or somehow) in order not to be ignored right off. It is not too exhaustive a description to be added even though the results following, essential to point out, tells us just how long standing. Making both statements in less than two phrases would be too terse even for a resume.

The age of the bug is answered in the second part, telling how what you did affected others. Very important.
I think using "Credited" tells them that everyone knows it was you who did it. We all solve bugs for a living. This one needs a bit of extra verbiage. Well done.

Comment: Thanks! A couple follow ups. Doesn't "solving years of difficulty" already imply "long standing?" i.e., if I just said "Solved bug that caused years of difficulty" doesn't that get the same point across? this is a bit of a trivial thing semantically, but I wanted this to fit on one line in my resume hah

Comment: And agreed about the "solved" instead of "debugged." Actually changed it in my resume to that after I made the OP

Answer (score 1):

describe the bug as “persistent”

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).